# Java Mapper: finding the number of customers who purchased both item IDs 21 and 27

Tags: java

I would like to create a map function for a retail dataset with input key as long integer offset and input value as a line of text. The output key of the map is the text Both_21_27 and the output value is constant integer value 1.

In the map, two boolean variables item_21 and item_27 should be created and initialized to false. After changing value to string, StringTokenizer is used to have strings into tokens.

With each token, each token has to be iterated to see if it matches with 21 or 27. If there is a match, the corresponding boolean variable is changed to true. The switch condition can be used for checking.

After going through all the tokens, both the boolean variables should be true or not. If both boolean variables are false or one is true and one is false, then else return; statement should be used to skip the transaction and move on to the next.

A sample retail dataset is shown below:

```js
2 7 15 21 32 41 
5 14 19 21 25 27 45 57 62 75 80 
1 3 7 15 19 21 26 27 35 44 54 
2 9 16 24 35 41 49 57 68 72 88 
4 23 31 33 42 45 67 73 92 
9 12 18 21 22 24 27 43 74 
15 19 45 47 53 58 64 79 83 94 99 107
3 7 15 17 21 23 26 27 33 42 44 47 49 55 62 77 82
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class RetailMapper
  extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

  private Text Both_21_27 = new Text();
  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  
  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
 boolean item_21 = false;
 boolean item_27 = false;
    StringTokenizer item = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
 
 while (item.hasMoreTokens()) {
 Both_21_27.set(item.nextToken());
 context.write(Both_21_27, one);
 }
 switch(item) {
  case 21 :
   item_21 = true;
   break;
  case 27 :
   item_27 = true;
   break;
 }
    if (item_21 = true && item_27 = true) {
      context.write(Both_21_27, one);
 else return;
 }
}

  }
```

I am stuck with this map function. Any help, advice, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move `switch` block into `while` loop.

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    boolean item_39 = false;
    boolean item_48 = false;
    StringTokenizer item = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

    while (item.hasMoreTokens()) {
    Both_39_48.set(item.nextToken());
    context.write(Both_39_48, one);
    switch((Integer)item.nextElement()) { // use nextElement and convert to int
        case 39 :
            item_39 = true;
            break;
        case 48 :
            item_48 = true;
            break;
    }
    }

    if (item_39 && item_48) {
      context.write(Both_39_48, one);
    }
    else return;

}
```